# How to make a list element clickable and redirect to a url in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue.js. I have a nav bar set up and it has a bunch of list elements. I would like one of my list elements to go to another website for example, https://www.google.com/. I have a router file that has multiple children (for each element in my list), and for each child there are three components,

the path, component, name.

In the nav bar I have everything set up like this,

```
<li v-bind:class="{active: $route.name == '//name from router file for   
that child'}">
  <router-link to="//path for that child">Google</router-link>
</li>
```

I have created a vue file for the route.name which is Google.vue. The way this is set up, I have everything added onto the localhost path name. However, I want this particular list element to go to www.google.com instead of adding onto the path.
Is this possible? if it is, where should I add this link to?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an anchor tag instead of a router link

```
<li>
    <a class="text-link" href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</li>
```

And style it however you wish

```
.text-link,
.text-link:active,
.text-link:focus,
.text-link:hover,
.text-link:visited {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For updated question:

Option 1: Remove `<router-link>` tag and have your link look like:

```html
<li @click="redirect('https://google.com')" v-bind:class="{active: $route.name == '//name from router file for   
that child'}"></li>
```

`... in your .vue file
    redirect: function (url) {
      window.location=url;
    }`

Option 2: Add navigation guard to your google route.

`{
    path: '/google',
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        window.location = "https://google.com";
    }
}`

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks

Comment: Because I don't want it to look like a link but rather a text element but still clickable if that makes sense

Comment: Ok then the easiest way is probably to make a redirect method. So have something like:

`<li @click="redirect('https://www.google.com/')">Go to google</li>`

Then in your main js file or component create a method:

`redirect: function (url) {
      window.location=url;
    }`

Comment: Alright I think I want to change how this works. My other list elements work through a router-link. Let me update the question.

Comment: The first option, in the vue file it should be inside script tags right?
I did that and I'm getting a "Identifier expected" error at "(url)"

Comment: `<script>
    export default {
        methods: {    
redirect: function (url) {
      window.location=url;
    }
        }
    }
</script>`

Comment: How should it be set up in router file? right now I have this for the child => 

    component: Google,
    name: 'Google'

Comment: This is a good start for what your router should look like. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Try adding the redirect method to your main js file where you initialize the Vue instance instead of to the child component.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

`<li v-on:click="window.location='https://www.google.com/'">Go to Google</li>`

Comment: This doesn't work. But thanks for this suggestion :D